# How to use bindonce

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularfire

Does bindonce work with angularfire? It seems to me that the once watch triggers before the data is loaded from firebase. What's the correct pattern to use bindonce with angularfire?

Comment: What version of angular? Which bindonce?

Comment: @aet bindoncev0.3.1 and angularv1.2.16

Comment: Could you possibly show a little bit of the code in question? (I have only dabbled with angularfire, but I've used - or tried to - bindonce a good bit.)